# Crystal reporting- sum on group summary

Tags: crystal-reports

At level of group 1, I want sum of summaries of Group2. 
And at report header, I want to display group 1 summaries.

•   Group 1 - **3**         //sum of group2 summary

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 0

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 0

•   Group 1 - **4**           //sum of summary of group 2

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 0

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 1

o   Group2 - 1

Thanks for your valued suggestions

Answer (score 2):

- create formula field.
- add this to your field : sum({Field.Name},{DataTable1.Groupname})

  - Field.Name is your field that you need to sum.
  - DataTable1.Groupname is your require group for that.
- drag and drop formula field at your required place.

You create fields according to your requirement now.
If you need any help then let me know.

**J**